# Bash script to compare/search two directories using file list as variable

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to write a bash script that will allow me to grab the names of files on Dir1 for example, and use EACH file name as my search string in the find command, and run the find command on Dir2. Then, output the search results to a text file.

So, for example, when it runs it will:

> Get files in Dir1:
>
> - file1.txt
> - file2.txt
> - file3.txt
> - file4.txt
>
> Find any files in Dir2 with "file1" in name
>
> file1 exists in Dir2 as "file1-extrafile.txt"
>
> Write result to text file
>
> Repeat using "file2" as search string.

How can I do this? Will `diff` help me? A `for` loop?

Comment: This is untested, but try `for FILE in \`find '/path/to/dir1'\`; do find '/path/to/dir2' -name '*$FILE*' >> /path/to/result.txt; done`

Comment: Do you care about sub-directories of Dir1 and Dir2? Do you want sub-dirs included or ignored?

Comment: How do you want different extensions handled? Do you only care about .txt files? Or do you want to ignore any extension?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @EmilSit Sub directories must be searched as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for f in /dir1/*; do
  n=$(basename "$f")
  ls -1 /dir2/*${n%.*}*.${n##*.}
done > result.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find Dir1 -type f -printf '%f\0' | xargs -0 -n1 find Dir2 -name
```

Given files:

```
Dir1/a/b/c
Dir1/a/d
Dir1/e

Dir2/a/b
Dir2/a/e
Dir2/d
Dir2/c
Dir2/e/f
```

Will print:

```
Dir2/c
Dir2/d
Dir2/a/e
Dir2/e
```

Comment: You can use `-print0` instead.

Comment: `-print0` would be equivalent to `-printf '%p\0'`, which wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a file (say `search.sh`) and execute it with `./search.sh dir1 dir2`

```
#!/bin/sh

dir1=$1
dir2=$2
[ -z "$dir1" -o -z "$dir2" ] && echo "$0 dir1 dir2" 1>&2 && exit 1

#
# Stash contents of dir2 for easy searching later
#
dir2cache=/tmp/dir2.$$
# Clean up after ourselves
trap "rm -f $dir2cache" 0 1 2 15
# Populate the cache
find $dir2 -type f > $dir2cache

#
# Iterate over patterns and search against cache
#
for f in $(find $dir1 -type f); do
    # Extract base name without extension
    n=$(basename $f .txt)
    # Search for files that begin with base name in the cache
    fgrep "/$n" $dir2cache
done
```